# Deduplication of records

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have dimension data related to all stores, I need to identify the duplicates (which represent same stores) in the records - Data is incomplete and has a lot of missing values -

I have tried

- Dedupe
- Record Linkage

Appreciate any help on how to solve the problem

TIA

S

Answer (score 0):

Use MySql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deduplicate()
BEGIN

    SELECT DISTINCT stores from storeDatabase ;  
END
```

the keyword "DISTINCT" will make it so that the table that is returned will only have unique observations in the stores column.

Comment: Hi Nathan,  Appreciate your comments

Comment: However, my dataset is a set of unique/distinct records which has duplicates. The intent is to identify the association/relationship between variables and identify unique stores using Machine Learning.